# fsck_apfs error 'Container superblock is invalid'

Tags: hard-drive, partition, mount

I'm trying to mount an old external SSD with an encrypted APFS volume on it.

Disk Utility shows it as Not Mounted and attempting to mount it results in the following:

> Could not mount “disk2s2”. (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error -119930868.)

Disk Utility First Aid on the disk shows ‘The partition map appears to be OK’ and no issues reported. First Aid on the volume isn't possible, as the option is greyed out.

`fsck_apfs` is also not happy, returning

> error: Device does not contain a valid APFS container.
> Container superblock is invalid.

Here's the output of `diskutil list` and `fsck_apfs`.

```
$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS                         499.9 GB   disk2s2

$ sudo fsck_apfs /dev/disk2
0000:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00fe       |................|
01c0:  ffff eefe ffff 0100 0000 ff5f 383a 0000       |............8...|
01d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
0200:  4546 4920 5041 5254 0000 0100 5c00 0000       |EFI.PART........|
0210:  96f5 54be 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000       |..T.............|
0220:  ff5f 383a 0000 0000 2200 0000 0000 0000       |..8.............|
0230:  de5f 383a 0000 0000 a8b0 39fd 4b4b c648       |..8.......9.KK.H|
0240:  b814 49a3 9175 b71a 0200 0000 0000 0000       |..I..u..........|
0250:  8000 0000 8000 0000 f696 6c12 0000 0000       |..........l.....|
0260:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0400:  2873 2ac1 1ff8 d211 ba4b 00a0 c93e c93b       |.s.......K......|
0410:  92e8 8efc df20 0442 94ac ad19 1e9e 54ef       |.......B......T.|
0420:  2800 0000 0000 0000 2740 0600 0000 0000       |................|
0430:  0000 0000 0000 0000 4500 4600 4900 2000       |........E.F.I...|
0440:  5300 7900 7300 7400 6500 6d00 2000 5000       |S.y.s.t.e.m...P.|
0450:  6100 7200 7400 6900 7400 6900 6f00 6e00       |a.r.t.i.t.i.o.n.|
0460:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0480:  ef57 347c 0000 aa11 aa11 0030 6543 ecac       |.W4........0eC..|
0490:  6694 dc64 e4e5 2f4b b022 8513 5bb1 06e9       |f..d...K........|
04a0:  2840 0600 0000 0000 d75f 383a 0000 0000       |..........8.....|
04b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0ff0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|

error: Device does not contain a valid APFS container.
   Container superblock is invalid.
** The container /dev/disk2 could not be verified completely.

$ sudo fsck_apfs /dev/disk2s2
0000:  eb58 9042 5344 2020 342e 3400 0240 2000       |.X.BSD..4.4.....|
0010:  0200 0000 00f8 0000 2000 ff00 2840 0600       |................|
0020:  b01f 323a 74d1 0100 0000 0000 0200 0000       |..2.t...........|
0030:  0100 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
0040:  8000 29fa 1773 6f55 4e54 4954 4c45 4420       |.....soUNTITLED.|
0050:  2020 4641 5433 3220 2020 fa31 c08e d0bc       |..FAT32....1....|
0060:  007c fb8e d8e8 0000 5e83 c619 bb07 00fc       |................|
0070:  ac84 c074 06b4 0ecd 10eb f530 e4cd 16cd       |...t.......0....|
0080:  190d 0a4e 6f6e 2d73 7973 7465 6d20 6469       |...Non.system.di|
0090:  736b 0d0a 5072 6573 7320 616e 7920 6b65       |sk..Press.any.ke|
00a0:  7920 746f 2072 6562 6f6f 740d 0a00 0000       |y.to.reboot.....|
00b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
0200:  5252 6141 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |RRaA............|
0210:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
03e0:  0000 0000 7272 4161 f1b9 e800 0300 0000       |....rrAa........|
03f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
0400:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0c00:  eb58 9042 5344 2020 342e 3400 0240 2000       |.X.BSD..4.4.....|
0c10:  0200 0000 00f8 0000 2000 ff00 2840 0600       |................|
0c20:  b01f 323a 74d1 0100 0000 0000 0200 0000       |..2.t...........|
0c30:  0100 0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
0c40:  8000 29fa 1773 6f55 4e54 4954 4c45 4420       |.....soUNTITLED.|
0c50:  2020 4641 5433 3220 2020 fa31 c08e d0bc       |..FAT32....1....|
0c60:  007c fb8e d8e8 0000 5e83 c619 bb07 00fc       |................|
0c70:  ac84 c074 06b4 0ecd 10eb f530 e4cd 16cd       |...t.......0....|
0c80:  190d 0a4e 6f6e 2d73 7973 7465 6d20 6469       |...Non.system.di|
0c90:  736b 0d0a 5072 6573 7320 616e 7920 6b65       |sk..Press.any.ke|
0ca0:  7920 746f 2072 6562 6f6f 740d 0a00 0000       |y.to.reboot.....|
0cb0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0df0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|
0e00:  5252 6141 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |RRaA............|
0e10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000       |................|
. . .
0fe0:  0000 0000 7272 4161 f1b9 e800 0300 0000       |....rrAa........|
0ff0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 55aa       |..............U.|

error: Device does not contain a valid APFS container.
   Container superblock is invalid.
** The container /dev/disk2s2 could not be verified completely.

$ sudo fsck_msdos -n /dev/rdisk2s2
** /dev/rdisk2s2
** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT
** Phase 2 - Checking Directories
** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters
0 files, 488062496 KiB free (15251953 clusters)
```

What are my next steps?